# Jquery - Remove / empty added text

Tags: jquery, append

When the button is clicked, a text is suppose to be displayed and I am trying to remove the text(so when you click the button again the same text will be displayed and just once)-but it doesn't work...

html:

```
    <button class="button2"id="hints">
     <p ><b>hint</b></p>
        </button>        
  </div>
  <div id="hintText">         
  </div>
```

JS:

```
$('#hints').on('click',function(){
$('#hintText').append("The correct number is either 15, 99 or " + user);
$('#hintText').empty();
});
```

Comment: What exactly you want to do? Please specify properly.

Comment: Do you want to show the text once and then want to hide it automatically? if you are looking for this then you can use .hide().

Answer (score 0):

you just need to change the line order

```
$('#hints').on('click',function(){
$('#hintText').empty();
$('#hintText').append("The correct number is either 15, 99 or " + user);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand exactly what you are wanting to do but I will try to help you.

Are you trying to show the hint for a short period (keeping "hintText" div)?

HTML:

```
<button class="button2"id="hints">hint</button>        
<div id="hintText">         
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#hints').on('click',function(){
    $('#hintText').text("The correct number is either 15, 99 or " + user);

    setTimeout(function(){
         $('#hintText').empty();
    }, 1000 /* show it for 1 second */);
});
```

Are you trying to show it and hide it on button click?

HTML:

```
<button class="button2"id="hints">hint</button>        
<div id="hintText">         
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#hints').on('click',function(){
    $('#hintText').text("The correct number is either 15, 99 or " + user);
    $('#hintText').toggle();
});
```

PS. If the hint text is static according to user, I mean, if "user" variable is a constant, you can put it outside of the click event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first make the element empty then append the text in it.I tried your code in this way

```
 $('#hints').on('click',function(){
   $('#hintText').empty();
   $('#hintText').append("The correct number is either 15, 99 or "+user);
 });
```

It is giving me proper output.

Please let me know if it help you.

Comment: Thank you-I wasn't explaining well what I was trying to do but it helped!! Before, every time I would click the button the same text would be displayed over and over, now if I click the button the text is being displayed only once and if I click it again, nothing happens(which I wanted). Can you explain please why putting ...empty() before append makes that work? Thank you!

Comment: While putting empty() it will make the content of the div null.So when next time it clicks ,it append the new content.Hope this will help